# Placement input text no showing

Tags: django

When I add another CRSF Token, it will not show the placeholder texts. Without this second token. It will not allow for me to save the form. I do not know how to make this last placeholder visible again when adding the token.

Any Help would be appreciated. If any other files are needed such as the views class. I can provide this however I believe its to do with something in the html document.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        
    <head>
    

    <title>Register</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        body,
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            background: #7abecc !important;
        }
        .user_card {
            width: 350px;
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            background: #74cfbf;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            border-radius: 5px;

        }

        .form_container {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        #form-title{
            color: #fff;
        }
        .login_btn {
            width: 100%;
            background: #33ccff !important;
            color: white !important;
        }
        .login_btn:focus {
            box-shadow: none !important;
            outline: 0px !important;
        }
        .login_container {
            padding: 0 2rem;
        }
        .input-group-text {
            background: #f7ba5b !important;
            color: white !important;
            border: 0 !important;
            border-radius: 0.25rem 0 0 0.25rem !important;
        }
        .input_user,
        .input_pass:focus {
            box-shadow: none !important;
            outline: 0px !important;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
            <div class="user_card">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <h3 id="form-title">REGISTER ACCOUNT</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">

                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form.userID}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form.name}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form.dateOfBirth}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form.homeAddress}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form.password1}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form.password2}}
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{form2.SNI}}
                        </div>

                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                            <input class="btn login_btn" type="submit" value="Register Account">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                {{form.errors}}
                <div class="mt-4">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
                        Already have an account? <a href="{% url 'loginPage' %}" class="ml-2">Login</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
                        /* Because i didnt set placeholder values in forms.py they will be set here using vanilla Javascript
        //We start indexing at one because CSRF_token is considered and input field 
         */

        //Query All input fields
        var form_fields = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
        form_fields[1].placeholder='UserID...(Email)';
        form_fields[2].placeholder='Full Name...';
        form_fields[3].placeholder='Date Of Birth...';
        form_fields[4].placeholder='Home Address...';
        form_fields[5].placeholder='Enter password...';
        form_fields[6].placeholder='Re-enter Password...';
        form_fields[7].placeholder='SNI Number...';


        for (var field in form_fields){ 
            form_fields[field].className += ' form-control'
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Register View]

Answer (score 0):

It's because the csrf token overwrites the value of the form.
I wouldn't recommend using a placeholder.

Try it with a label.

Comment: Sorry, how would i do this?

Comment: First remove the current Placeholder. Then add a label for each input like so <label for="INPUT_ID">Full Name</label> for example. You add a label for each input. Inside the label in for="" you put the id of the input. With css you can edit the labels

Comment: is this ID the ID from the forms or ?